# Why are my army levies decreasing?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I built barracks to increase the levy size in my capital, then i sent my marshal to train troops and the army levies started to increase rapidly. Then it proceeded to decrease rapidly and my marshal was still training the troops in the capital. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Did anything happen which reduced your personal martial skill? Levy size is affected by the martial of the person governing the holding.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to give you a guaranteed answer without more information (a series of screenshots, or video, etc). However, there are a number of things that can cause a reduction in the number of available levy troops. I'll try to list them; hopefully you can find the one that happened to you (although that is unlikely given that you asked this question two years ago...)

1. Your **personal Martial attribute** changed. This changes the maximum available levy size (by 5% per point); if you have more levy troops available than the maximum for your holding, they will disappear. Many, *many* things can cause your attributes to change - far more than is appropriate to go into here...
2. Your **Marshal's Martial attribute** changed. Since he was training troops, he was also applying a 2.5% per point boost to the maximum available levy troops. The same logic applies here as for #1.
3. **You moved your Capital.** This also impacts the levy cap directly.
4. **Disease.** This may be the most likely culprit, especially if your levy cap was *not* affected. There exists, unfortunately, very little (if any!) documentation of this effect, but I have experienced it and it is referenced [in The Reaper's Due](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/The_Reaper%27s_Due#DLC_features) DLC description. (see comment)

Hopefully you recognize one of these as being the cause of your problem, and hopefully I didn't miss any. I did leave out the impact of e.g. sieges and raids, because those are pretty obvious - if you were losing troops to an invading army or band of looters, I suspect you would have noticed.

Comment: With regards to Point #4: I have no evidence beyond the anecdotal, but I believe this effect is not limited to The Reaper's Due DLC. I do not own this DLC. However, I have *definitely* experienced the depleted-garrisons effect from disease. A shame there is no documentation on the Wiki for this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Izzy's excellent answer, you could be losing levies owed to you by your vassals.

Your vassals will give you less money and levies if they don't like you, so it could be that one of your more powerful vassals opinion of you dropped which caused the levies they owe you to drop.